# Type of error landig.Slots is undefined in react js

Tags: json, reactjs, parsing, product

> **type of error landig.Slots is undefined**

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import Slot from "../components/slot";
import LandingLoader from "./landing-loader";
import ListingsContainer from "crust/containers/listings";

class Landing extends React.Component {
  state = {
    flexHeight: "auto"
  };

  setHeight(height) {
    if (this.default) {
      this.default.style = `height:${height}px; overflow:hidden`;
    }
  }

  render() {
    let { error, land
```

ing, slotsLoaded, slotsToLoad, showListings } = this.props;
    let ready = landing && slotsLoaded;
    return (
       (this.default = ref)}
        style={
          showListings
            ? {
                height: "auto",
                overflow: "auto",
                overflowX: "hidden"
              }
            : {}
        }>
        
          
          
        
        
          
          
            {landing &&
              landing.Slots.map((slot,index) => {
                if (slot && !slot.removed) {
                  let fullWidth = "100%";
                  let maxWidth = 576;

```
              let style = {};
              style["width"] = fullWidth;
              style["maxWidth"] = fullWidth;
              style["height"] = slot.HeightPixel + "px";

              return (
                <li key={index} className="slots" style={style}>
                  <Slot slotItem={slot} slotIndex={index} />
                </li>
              );
            }
          })}
      </ul>
    </main>
  </div>
);
```

}
}

export default connect(state => state)(Landing);

Comment: Please fix your code formatting

Comment: @SergGr your edit did not work

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi, I only removed the `algorithm` tag that is clearly irrelevant. I think Lidiya has to improve the question on her own.

Comment: If i given proper title in tag then its not accepting my post. so only i did like that. Actually am getting error like "type of error landig.Slots is undefined in line no:50"